# NHibernate not finding named query result sets in 2nd level cache

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

I have a simple unit test where I execute the same NHibernate named query 2 times (different session each time) with the identical parameter.  It's a simple int parameter, and since my query is a named query I assume these 2 calls are identical and the results should be cached.

In fact, I can see in my log that the results ARE being cached, but with different keys.  So, my 2nd query results are never found in cache.

here's a snip from my log (note how the keys are different):

(first query)

> DEBUG NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheRegion [(null)] <(null)> -
>   adding new data: key=  [snipped]... parameters: ['809']; named
>   parameters: {}@**743460424** &
>   value=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

(second query)

> DEBUG NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheRegion [(null)] <(null)> -
>   adding new data: key=[snipped]... parameters: ['809']; named
>   parameters: {}@**704749285** &
>   value=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

I have NHibernate set up to use the query cache.  And I have these queries set to cacheable=true.  Don't know where else to look.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
-Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - i figured this out.   I was executing my named query using the following syntax:

```
IQuery q = session.GetNamedQuery("MyQuery")
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(MyDTO)))
                .SetCacheable(true)
                .SetCacheRegion("MyCacheRegion");
```

( which, I might add, is **EXACTLY** how the NHibernate docs tell you how to do it.. but I digress ;)  )

If you use create a new AliasToBean Transformer for every query, then each query object (*which is the key to the cache*) will be unique and you will never get a cache hit.  So, in short, if you do it like the nhib docs say then caching wont work.

Instead, create your transformer one time in a static member var and then use that for your query, and caching will work - like this:

```
private static IResultTransformer myTransformer = Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(MyDTO))
```

...

```
IQuery q = session.GetNamedQuery("MyQuery")
                    .SetResultTransformer(myTransformer)
                    .SetCacheable(true)
                    .SetCacheRegion("MyCacheRegion");
```

Comment: The docs make no reference to transformers in the context of caching. The behavior makes sense.

Comment: It only makes sense once you study the logs and see what's going on. :)

Comment: nice one, came across this myself and thought was sure i'd done something wrong.

Comment: Wow! this is a crazy one! thanks